# IntelliJ "end" smart key on click

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, the "end" smart key jumps to a reasonable indentation based on the current code style, when pressed while the caret is on an empty line. However, when I click on an empty line, I almost never want the caret to be on the start of the line to begin with.

Consider the following use case: Two blocks of code are separated by an empty line. My intent is to append a line to the first block. For this, I do the following:

1. Click on the empty line. The caret jumps to the start of the line.
2. Hit the end key. The caret jumps forward to the right indentation.
3. Write some line of code and hit enter.

My question now is: Is there a setting in IntelliJ to do step 2 automatically, when an empty line is clicked?

Note, that this is not done by the virtual space after line break option, since this enables me to put the caret where I clicked, not at the right indentation.
Also, I am aware that it is possible to just leave whitespaces everywhere by disabling the option of auto-trimming leading whitespaces. However, I would like to have a cleaner solution to the problem.

Here is an [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO7Yr.png):
I click at position 1 and the caret jumps to 2. I want the caret to jump to 3 immediately instead.